# Best programs to to install on Mac OS X with Macports

Tags: macos, mac, macports

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some “must have” Mac OS X programs?](https://superuser.com/questions/1191/what-are-some-must-have-mac-os-x-programs)

What are the must-have programs to install on a Mac with Macports?  One per answer please...

Or, if you prefer not to use macports, please indicate so and why.....

Thanx

Comment: Another community-wiki candidate, based on its subjectivity?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://superuser.com/questions/4939/must-have-open-source-software

Comment: @peelman -- your link seems to be a generic 'best OSS'.  My question is Mac specific, and Macports specific.

Comment: @rob, yes it is subjective.

Comment: These type of "questions" are discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The programs you find you need to use.

I know that sounds like a smart-ass answer, but I install programs from MacPorts (or any programs) as I need them.

Answer (score 0):

mipadi gave the proper answer: install what you need.

That said, the main MacPort I've installed is GraphViz (the Mac version doesn't integrate as nicely into the command line).  Its a graph drawing app that operates based on a list of commands (think LaTeX).